# Why is this outputting "none" each time I ask the user for an input?

Tags: python

Hello everyone this is a sample code that I am working on for our school work.

```
class Item:
    
    list = []
    
    def __init__ (self, name, num):
        Item.list.append(self)
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
        
bread = Item("Bread", 20)
rice = Item("Rice", 30)
fruits = Item("Fruits", 40)
vegetables = Item("Vegetables", 25)
meat = Item("Meat", 35)

for i in Item.list:
    print(f"{i.name}, {i.num}")

def withdraw():
    b = int(input(print("\nHow many bread would you take? "))) 
    r = int(input(print("\nHow many rice would you take? ")))  
    f = int(input(print("\nHow many fruits would you take? "))) 
    v = int(input(print("\nHow many vegetables would you take? ")))
    m = int(input(print("\nHow many meat would you take? ")))
   
    bread.num = bread.num - b
    rice.num = rice.num - r
    fruits.num = fruits.num - f
    vegetables.num = vegetables.num - v
    meat.num = meat.num - m
withdraw()

for i in Item.list:
    print(f"{i.name} : {i.num}")
```

The output every time it prints is like this

```
How many bread would you take
None
```

Why is it printing None? and how can I stop that. Thanks.

Comment: Change `int(input(print("\nHow many bread would you take? ")))` to `int(input("\nHow many bread would you take? "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing these:

```py
b = int(input(print("\nHow many bread would you take? "))) 
r = int(input(print("\nHow many rice would you take? ")))  
f = int(input(print("\nHow many fruits would you take? "))) 
v = int(input(print("\nHow many vegetables would you take? ")))
m = int(input(print("\nHow many meat would you take? ")))
```

to:

```py
b = int(input("\nHow many bread would you take? ")) 
r = int(input("\nHow many rice would you take? "))  
f = int(input("\nHow many fruits would you take? ")) 
v = int(input("\nHow many vegetables would you take? "))
m = int(input("\nHow many meat would you take? "))
```

Comment: some explanation: the `input` function takes care of printing the the question, you don't need `print`. The `print` function returns `None` and that's why it was printed in the original code.

Comment: Thanks friend, I actually just realized it as soon as I took a second look at it. Anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: Recommendation: please mark answer as accepted if you are new to SO. This helps with increasing reputation of the person who wrote it. There will be a gray checkmark below voting poll for the same